# customizing checkboxes and radio buttons using CSS3

Tags: html, css

Here i'm having checkboxes and radiobuttons with respective styles

**HTML**

```
<h3>Radio buttons</h3>
<div class="radio">
  <input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="Data1" value="agree" checked />
  <label for="radio-1">Yes</label>
  <input id="radio-2" type="radio" name="Data1" value="disagree" />
  <label for="radio-2">No</label>
</div>
<h3>Checkboxes</h3>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" name="Data2" value="option1" checked />
  <label for="checkbox-1">HTML</label>
  <br />
  <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" name="Data3" value="option2" />
  <label for="checkbox-2">CSS</label>
</div>
```

i want to change the image on **:hover** , how can i do this

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/)

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label:hover:before, input[type=radio] + label:hover:before{
   background: url('http://cnt.in.bookmyshow.com/bmsin/SLIMG/1_2.gif?v1'); 
}
```

Is combines two css pseudo classes - `:hover:before` to achieve the effect.

I also changed your 'selected' background code from:

```
background: url('http://cnt.in.bookmyshow.com/bmsin/SLIMG/1_4.gif') !important;
```

to

```
background: url('http://cnt.in.bookmyshow.com/bmsin/SLIMG/1_4.gif');
```

This is to stop the icon turning from green to grey on hover.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/tT6tD/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {display: none;}
input[type="checkbox"] + label, input[type="radio"] + label {padding-left: 20px;}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/LpSXDFI.png') no-repeat 0 center;}
input[type="radio"] + label {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/YWUFP1H.png') no-repeat 0 center;}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/xS4jaLI.png') no-repeat 0 center;}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label, input[type="checkbox"]:hover + label {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/xS4jaLI.png') no-repeat 0 center;}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label, input[type="radio"]:hover + label {background: url('http://i.imgur.com/q4VadN4.png') no-repeat 0 center;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P8Qrq/4/